# How to automatically add a task to Astrid?

Tags: automation, tasker, astrid

I would like to automatically add tasks to Astrid. For example, a task to chare the tablet when battery is low or a task for an epsiode the just runs according to EpisodeCalendar.
I am using Tasker and I have the Locale Astrid plugin, but I cannot find any option to actually add a task.

I found the solution to send a mail to tasks@astrid.com, but as my phone is in airplane mode at night, I am missing a lot of tasks when internet connection is required. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a really satisfying solution, but it is still better than nothing (really disappointed by Astrid, BTW):
According to the author, the App "Locale SendSilentMail Plug-In" by Stafan Dörr maintains a queue, so Mails are not lost if there is no connection to the mail server. This is sufficient for my cause, though not very elegant.